# Pandas ignore non-numeric values

Tags: python, pandas

I have this df:

```
     X
0   13500
1   13600
2   BBOX-001
3   Mobi-1
4   15003
5   15004
```

I am trying to enter a new column. if x >15000 then the value is A, otherwise B. If X is non-numeric (BBOX-001, Mobi-1), then it should display the value in column X:

```
     X        Y
0   13500     B
1   13600     B
2   BBOX-001  BBOX-001
3   Mobi-1    Mobi-1
4   15003     A
5   15004     A
```

I have this below but how do I ignore the non-numeric values in column X?

```
df['Y'] = np.where(df['X'] > 15000, 'A', 'B')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `df['X']` contains a mix of numbers and strings, the dtype of the column will be `object` instead of a numeric dtype. The number-like items in `df['X']` may be ints or floats or maybe even strings (it's unclear from your question).
Many numeric operations such as `df['X'] > 15000` may raise errors in this case.

To treat the number-like  values as numbers, use `pd.to_numeric` to convert the column into a numeric dtype:

```
In [41]: numeric_X = pd.to_numeric(df['X'], errors='coerce')
In [43]: numeric_X
Out[43]: 
0    13500.0
1    13600.0
2        NaN
3        NaN
4    15003.0
5    15004.0
Name: X, dtype: float64
```

And you can also identify the string-like values by testing for NaNs:

```
is_stringlike = np.isnan(numeric_X)
```

---

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'X': ['13500', '13600', 'BBOX-001', 'Mobi-1', '15003', '15004']})

numeric_X = pd.to_numeric(df['X'], errors='coerce')
is_stringlike = np.isnan(numeric_X)
conditions = [numeric_X > 15000, is_stringlike]
choices = ['A', df['X']]
df['Y'] = (np.select(conditions, choices, default='B'))
print(df)
```

yields

```
          X         Y
0     13500         B
1     13600         B
2  BBOX-001  BBOX-001
3    Mobi-1    Mobi-1
4     15003         A
5     15004         A
```

Answer (score 1):

You may achieve your goal with `convert_objects`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'X': ['13500', '13600', 'BBOX-001', 'Mobi-1', '15003', '15004']})
# Convert only numeric value to put it in comparison
df['Y'] = np.where(df.X.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True) > 15000, 'A', 'B')

print (df)
```

Output:

```
         X  Y
0     13500  B
1     13600  B
2  BBOX-001  B
3    Mobi-1  B
4     15003  A
5     15004  A
```